# LDAP группа контактов для Outlook

Tags: postfix, outlook, ldap, контакты

Здравствуйте, у меня настроен почтовый сервер на Postfix.

Я реализовал общую адресную книгу используя контакты LDAP (AD). Эта адресная книга успешно подключилась. Теперь мне необходимо создать группу контактов для рассылки.

Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Postfix-у надо объяснить, что адрес рассылки, это определенное количество получателей.

Сделать это можно в файле `/etc/aliases` так:

```
sales:    user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com, user38@domain.com
```

В результате отправки письма на `sales@domain.com` - это письмо будет продублировано Postfix-ом всем получателям.

Если получателей много, то лучше их всех вынести в отдельный файл, например, `/etc/postfix/forwards/sales`, который будет содержать всех получателей по одному в строке:

```
user1@domain.com
user2@domain.com
user38@domain.com
user73@domain.com
и т.д.
```

а в файле `aliases` надо прописать такую строчку:

```
sales:     :include:/etc/postfix/forwards/sales
```

После манипуляций с файлом `aliases` не забываем про команду `newaliases`.

Comment: Суть в том, что я адресную книгу делаю на основе контактов AD а не Postfix для того, чтобы эта адресная книга была глобальная, для всех пользователей Outlook.

Comment: @Igor-Potapov покажите `postconf | grep '^alias_maps\|^virtual_alias_maps'`